# jquery + div wont hide correctly with .hide() when has property block?

Tags: jquery, css, html, hide

I have a div, that is added to my html with append...

I then hide it with `$('#'+q).hide();` where `q` is the variable name of my div.

this works 100%.

When triggered I then show the div with `$('#'+q).show();`. again this works 100% adn the div is shown.

my problem is, that when I want to hide it again, `$('#'+q).hide();` does not work. no javascript errors, it simply does not work.

The generated html, when the div is shown is:
`<div id="30" class="form" style="display: block;">`

I try to hide this div with `$('#'+q).hide();` where variable q = 30. I have confirmed the value of q.

this does not work an the html remains the same.

firebug highlights the html when `$('#'+q).hide();`  is called but does not change it so it seems to be getting refreshed, just not correctly so.

any ideas apprecaited.

Thanks as alway,Regards

Comment: Sounds like delegation problem??

Comment: Can you please show your code in context? Ideally if you could reduce it to a minimum sample that demonstrates the problem at http://jsfiddle.net that would really help us to help you. _"this does not work an the html remains the same"_ - Where are you looking at html? The browser doesn't update html for the page when changes are made, it updates the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide is in other way.

```
$('#'+q).css('display','none');
```

`.hide()` function internally changes `display:none` property to `display:block`. So if you `.hide()` is not working for some reason, then you can try above code.
Same is true for .show() as well i.e.

```
$('#'+q).css('display','block');
```

can be used for `.show()`.

Comment: Please provide a little more detail, i.e. why this solves the problem, if possible with relevant links to documentation.

Comment: Regarding your explanation, if `.hide()` tries to do that internally and it doesn't work, why would doing it with `.css()` work?

Comment: @nnnnnn as per my understanding, if the js version is older then it might not understand .show() function. not sure if i'm correct. I will be glad to know the exact answer. Please let me know, in case you know about it.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use the FireFox Web Developer plugin to see the generated code after changing it by JS/Jquery.[Firefox Web Developer PlugIn](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/web-developer/)

It is easier to use toggle() to show and hide elements.
Can you post the code that triggers the show() hide() functions on your element?

I've tried to reproduce some code in the following example:

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yBxW3/)

There is a block div:

```
<div id="30" class="form" style="display: block;">I am there</div>
<button>Toggle</button>
```

And you hide it:

```
$("#30").hide();
```

Then you can toggle it with the button:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#30").toggle();
});
```

Appending the div and the button to the body the code would look like:

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yBxW3/3/)

```
$("body").append('<div id="30" class="form" style="display: block;">I am there</div><button>Toggle</button>');
$("#30").hide();
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#30").toggle();
});
```

Hope this helps.